# Split string - By multiple character like {1} {2} {3}

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, split

I am having trouble splitting a string in c#.

For example the string: `"Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today"`

Should output will like this;

```
Hello World example today
```

I have tried with below code and it is working fine for me, but instead of declare 3 Delimiter I want any other way to achieve this.

```
String value = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today"; 
string strDelimitor = "{1}"; 
string strDelimitor1 = "{2}"; 
string strDelimitor2 = "{3}"; 
string[] lines = value.Split(new[] { strDelimitor }, StringSplitOptions.None); 
string first = lines[0].ToString();
string[] second = lines[1].Split(new[] { strDelimitor1 }, StringSplitOptions.None); 
string secondmsg = second[0].ToString(); 
string[] third = second[1].Split(new[] { strDelimitor2 }, StringSplitOptions.None); 
string Thirdmsg = third[0].ToString(); 
string fourthmsg = third[1].ToString();
```

Please help me to resolve this split question.

Comment: What have you tried? Is `{1}`,`{2}`.. are written exactly like that? Had a look at regex?

Comment: Show me the code what you'd tried to achieve it?

Comment: I think your question is wrong as your question is about split the string and the output you want is to remove the chracter. Split and remove the chracter are two different entities.

Comment: I have tried with below code and it is working fine for me, but instead of declare 3 Delimitor I want any other way to achieve this.                                                                                                  
 String value = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";
            string strDelimitor = "{1}";
            string strDelimitor1 = "{2}";
            string strDelimitor2 = "{3}";
string[] lines = value.Split(new[] { strDelimitor }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string first = lines[0].ToString();

Comment: string[] second = lines[1].Split(new[] { strDelimitor1 }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            string secondmsg = second[0].ToString();

            string[] third = second[1].Split(new[] { strDelimitor2 }, StringSplitOptions.None);


            string Thirdmsg = third[0].ToString();
            string fourthmsg = third[1].ToString();

Comment: @SandeepVerma Please add the code and your explanation to your question with the edit button. That much code in a comment is too hard to read.

Comment: @shamisheikh The .Split method removes the splitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I want to play too! Your input string has a space both before and after the numbers in brackets. I put one space after the numbers. Then there should be one space left between the words when the Join is performed.

```
 string s = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";
 string[] splitters = { "{1} ", "{2} ", "{3} " };
 string[] newS = s.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None);
 string Final = String.Join("",newS);
 Debug.Print(Final);
```

To use Debug.Print add a using statement System.Diagnostics

Comment: @SandeepVerma What if the string contains more digits inside curly braces like this: `"Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today {4} and 5"` ? Try using a more common approach.

Comment: @S.Akbari I agree that a more general solution is better but if the OP like myself is not familiar with regex and explanation of the method would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx):

Add this to your `using` directives first:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then:

```
string str = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";
string pattern = @"\{\d+\}";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(str, replacement);
```

`"\{\d+\}"` means: an open curly-brace followed by one or more digits (`d+`) followed by a close curly-brace.

Answer (score 1):

Use the String.Split method like this:

```
string[] separators   = new string[] { "{1}", "{2}", "{3}" };
string   myString     = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";
string[] splitStrings = myString.Split( separators,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

Comment: What if the string contains more curly braces containing digits, like this: `"Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today {4} and 5"` ?

Comment: If you have an unknown number of digits in curly braces it is the best idea to use the Regex approach mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *remove* the seperator strings do it like that:

```
string[] seperator = new string[] { "{1}", "{2}", "{3}" };
string   myString  = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";

foreach( string s in seperator )
{
    myString = myString.Replace( s, "" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `String` like this. This Code is simple

```
string s = "there is a cat";
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Output is:

> there
>
> is
>
> a
>
> cat

However You want to split multiple character then try this one. We use `Regex.Split` to separate based on multiple characters. There is an overloaded method if you need `StringSplitOptions`. This removes empty strings

```
string value = "cat\r\ndog\r\nanimal\r\nperson";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, "\r\n");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Output:

> cat
>
> dog
>
> animal
>
> person

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex (you will need to use the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//(...)
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\s?\{.\}\s?");
string result = rgx.Replace("Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today", " ");
// Hello World example today
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all numbers, curly brackets, whitespace, and just leave plain text so {14} etc would be removed could use this but its ugly

```
String test = "Hello {1} World {2} example {3} today";
char[] delimArray = { ' ','{','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '}' };
String [] test2 = test.Split(delimArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach( String s in test2)
{
System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```